# Subset Problem -- Any Materials?

Tags: c++, subset-sum

Yes this is a homework/lab assignment. 
I am interesting in coming up with/finding an algorithm (I can comprehend :P) for using "backtracking" to solve the subset sum problem.

Anyone have some helpful resources? I've spent the last hour or so Googling with not much like finding something I think I could actually use. xD

Thanks SO!

Comment: Can you elaborate on the "subset sum" problem.  It could have other names or even a brief description for those of us who have been out of school awhile.

Comment: @wheaties http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem and http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=subset+sum+backtracking

Answer (score 0):

Put the data in a vector.

Then write a routine that has 3 arguments: the vector, an index, and a sum.
Call this routine with the following arguments: the vector, 0, 0.

The routine should do the following tasks:

- check if we reached the end of the vector (index==size).  If this is the case, we can return immediately.
- call itself with arguments: the vector, index+1, sum+vector[index]
  (in this case we add the element at the index to the sum and continue with the vector)
- call itself with arguments: the vector, index+1, sum
  (in this case we don't add the element at the index to the sum, but still continue)

I deliberately left out 2 parts in this algorithm:

- first, you should check the sum at some point.  If it is zero, then you found a correct subset
- second, you should also pass knowledge about which elements you used, so if the sum is zero, you can print out the subset.  Consider using an STL::set for this.

Alternatively, you can use the return value of the function to determine whether a correct subset has already been found or not.

The complexity of the algorithm is O(2^N) so it will be very slow for big sets.

Have fun.